# role of non object when redirect role

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to log in multiple roles, 
when a user is **admin**, redirect to the admin page,
when a user is **guest**, redirect to the guest page,

this is my controller,

```
public function postLogin()
{
    if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
        echo "admin";
    }
   echo "guest";
}
```

but an error like this:

```
Trying to get property 'role' of non-object,
```

in table user be their **role** field;

what's wrong?

Comment: What is the package you have to use for managing roles and permissions?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Please create a relation before with particular model.

**User model** code:

```
public function userRole() {

    return $this->hasMany(User_Role_Table::class, 'user_Id')->join('roles_table', 'roles_table.id', '=', 'user_roles.role_Id')->select('roles_table.*', 'user_roles.user_Id');
}
```

You can call role like:

```
Auth::user()->userRole;
```

Answer (score 0):

This error **Trying to get property 'role' of non-object** says that the property role is trying to access a non-object. That means the **Auth::user()** is not a an object.

This happened in the case of the guest role. If you are logged in then **Auth::user()** is set and available as an object. But if you are not logged in and you are accessing the page without login then you will have no data in **Auth::user()**.

Solution to this problem is that you check if the object exists along with the **admin** check. Something like this-

```
public function postLogin()
{
    if(isset(Auth::user()->role) && Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
        echo "admin";
    }
    echo "guest";
}
```

My preferred version of this code-

```
public function postLogin()
    {
        if(isset(auth()->user()->role) && auth()->user()->role == 'admin') {
            echo "admin";
        }
        echo "guest";
    }
```

You can see I replaced **Auth::user()** with **auth()->user()**. I find it better than using the facade but it's up to you. Just an extra tip from my side.

Answer (score 0):

`Auth::user()` will return an instance of the logged in user, however, if the user isn't logged in this will return `null`.

If you're sure that your users will always have a `role` property on them then you can use the [check()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user) method:

```
if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role == 'admin') {
    echo 'admin';
}
```

This will first check that there is a currently logged in user and if there isn't fail before it gets to the next condition.

---

Alternatively, if you're using Laravel 5.5+ you could instead used the [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-optional) helper function

```
if (optional(Auth::user())->role == 'admin') {
    echo 'admin';
}
```

> The optional function accepts any argument and allows you to access properties or call methods on that object. If the given object is null, properties and methods will return null instead of causing an error: